# Ansible inventory structure for homogenous structure seperated by customer

Tags: ansible, structure, ansible-inventory, infrastructure-as-code

I have got a huge problem with structuring my inventory and how ansible merges groups in inventories.
Imagine an environment where the same three roles of servers stand in separate customer environments (e.g. backend, frontend, database). Those are also roles, which have roles-folders where tasks that should be executed, with default variables are collected. As suggested here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

My target is to have playbooks, which apply roles and their tasks, e.g. for upgrading the backend, frontend, and database separately PER CUSTOMER.

All in all, I would think about an inventory structure like that:

```
- inventories/   
  - customer1/
    - inventory.yml   
  - customer2/
    - inventory.yml
  - customer3/
    - inventory.yml
```

And one inventory.yml may contain e.g. the following structure:

```yaml
    all:
      children:
        customer1:
          children:
            frontend:
              hosts:
                fe01.customer1.com:
            backend:
              hosts:
                be01.customer1.com:
            database:
              hosts:
                db01.customer1.com:
```

The same would be in the other inventory files for customer2 and customer3 just exchanging the customer1.com domain respectively.

**Question 1:**
Why is it, and is this behavior anyhow changeable, that if I take the whole inventory as one when I use the following command:

```bash
shell> ansible customer1:&frontend --list-hosts
```

That I receive ALL hosts that are in any *frontend* group, although I have explicitly chosen customer1 AND frontend as selector groups:

```
    fe1.customer1.com
    fe1.customer2.com
    fe1.customer3.com
```

**Question 2:**
How would you structure your inventory to share variables between all customers, but also be able to target each customer solely, by using the *-i <inventory_file>* parameter, for a really big amount of customers?

e.g.:

```
shell> ansible -i inventories/customer1 fe --list-hosts
```

Thanks in advance, everybody have a nice day, and stay healthy!
Tim

Comment: I fixed the format of *inventory.yml*. But, there are details missing to answer the second question. [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score -1):

Given the inventory

```bash
shell> tree inventories
inventories
├── customer1
│   └── hosts.yml
├── customer2
│   └── hosts.yml
└── customer3
    └── hosts.yml

3 directories, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/customer1/hosts.yml 
all:
  children:
    customer1:
      children:
        frontend:
          hosts:
            fe01.customer1.com:
        backend:
          hosts:
            be01.customer1.com:
        database:
          hosts:
            db01.customer1.com:
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/customer2/hosts.yml 
all:
  children:
    customer2:
      children:
        frontend:
          hosts:
            fe01.customer2.com:
        backend:
          hosts:
            be01.customer2.com:
        database:
          hosts:
            db01.customer2.com:
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventories/customer3/hosts.yml 
all:
  children:
    customer3:
      children:
        frontend:
          hosts:
            fe01.customer3.com:
        backend:
          hosts:
            be01.customer3.com:
        database:
          hosts:
            db01.customer3.com:
```

---

Q: ***"If I take the whole inventory I receive all hosts in any frontend group. Why is it? Is this behavior anyhow changeable?"***

<sup>(Note: In the context of this question any references to the group customer* are irrelevant. See the outputs of *ansible-inventory* and the note below.)</sup>

A: It is because Ansible can combine inventory from multiple sources. See [Manage Ansible Inventory with dynamic and static hosts and vars](https://serverfault.com/questions/999032/manage-ansible-inventory-with-dynamic-and-static-hosts-and-vars). In particular:

> Ansible has several inventory plugins. You can combine them as multiple -i options or specify a directory containing multiple inventories.

This behavior is not changeable. Instead, you can configure [DEFAULT_HOST_LIST](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-host-list). If you set it to the directory *inventories* ('*the whole inventory as one*' in your terminology) you get

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=inventories ansible-inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    customer1:
      children:
        backend:
          hosts:
            be01.customer1.com: {}
            be01.customer2.com: {}
            be01.customer3.com: {}
        database:
          hosts:
            db01.customer1.com: {}
            db01.customer2.com: {}
            db01.customer3.com: {}
        frontend:
          hosts:
            fe01.customer1.com: {}
            fe01.customer2.com: {}
            fe01.customer3.com: {}
    customer2:
      children:
        backend:
          hosts:
            be01.customer1.com: {}
            be01.customer2.com: {}
            be01.customer3.com: {}
        database:
          hosts:
            db01.customer1.com: {}
            db01.customer2.com: {}
            db01.customer3.com: {}
        frontend:
          hosts:
            fe01.customer1.com: {}
            fe01.customer2.com: {}
            fe01.customer3.com: {}
    customer3:
      children:
        backend:
          hosts:
            be01.customer1.com: {}
            be01.customer2.com: {}
            be01.customer3.com: {}
        database:
          hosts:
            db01.customer1.com: {}
            db01.customer2.com: {}
            db01.customer3.com: {}
        frontend:
          hosts:
            fe01.customer1.com: {}
            fe01.customer2.com: {}
            fe01.customer3.com: {}
    ungrouped: {}
```

---

If you set it to the directory inventories/customer* you get

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=inventories/customer1 ansible-inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    customer1:
      children:
        backend:
          hosts:
            be01.customer1.com: {}
        database:
          hosts:
            db01.customer1.com: {}
        frontend:
          hosts:
            fe01.customer1.com: {}
    ungrouped: {}
```

---

This explains the output of the below commands

```bash
shell> ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=inventories ansible --list-hosts customer1:\&frontend
  hosts (3):
    fe01.customer1.com
    fe01.customer2.com
    fe01.customer3.com
```

```bash
shell> ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=inventories/customer1 ansible --list-hosts customer1:\&frontend
  hosts (1):
    fe01.customer1.com
```

---

Note: The [inventory pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#pattern-processing-order) `customer1:&frontend` is redundant. This pattern means: 'The hosts in the group *customer1* that are also members of the group *frontend*'. You can omit the *customer1* group because the group *frontend* is a subset of *customer1*. The commands below give the same results

```bash
shell> ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=inventories ansible --list-hosts frontend
shell> ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=inventories/customer1 ansible --list-hosts frontend
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you effor but I am really sorry, but that doesn't really answer my question about the conceptional decision I have to commit. it mostly just repeats my question. :(

Comment: I added mote details. HTH.